# How do I run a PowerShell script from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, powershell

If I have a .ps file in Visual Studio, how do I go about running it within the context of the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean by "from within the context of the project" but you can:

1. Create a `Process`

   ```
   Process p = new Process();
   ```
2. Then set the command of the process to be:

   ```
   powershell.exe YourScriptName.ps1
   ```

This works if you just need to run the script.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I need to alter a project file's xml, but am having a hard time accessing the path to the project dynamically, because this script will not run in the same location all of the time.

Answer (score 15):

I did this by adding a context menu item linked to an external tool:

Add an "External Tool". Go to Tools > External Tools. Add a new one with these settings:

- Title: `Run with Powershell`
- Command: `powershell.ex`
- Arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "$(ItemPath)"`
- Initial Directory: `$(ItemDir)`
- Check "`Use Output Window`"
- If you plan to use scripts that require arguments, check "`Prompt For Arguments`"

Take note of the position your tool is in the list (1,2, etc...) Click OK.

- Now go to `Tools` > `Customize`,  `Commands` tab,  select `Context Menu` or `Toolbar`, and choose "Project and Solution Context Menus | Item".
- Click "`Add Command...`".
- Choose `Tools` category, and choose "`External Command X`" where `x` is the position your tool was in the list (index starts with 1, not 0).
- Click `OK`.
- Move it to the position you want in the menu, and click "Modify Selection"
  to give it a friendly name,
- add keyboard shortcuts, etc..
- Click Close.

Right click your .ps1 file in the solution explorere and enjoy. (NOTE: I also did this for cmd.exe to run .bat files.)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to install the PowerGUI extension for Visual Studio 2010

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/01516103-d487-4a7e-bb40-c15ec709afa3/

One of the features of this extension is an integrated powershell tool window.  This has access to automation objects like `DTE` via `$EnvDTE` and will provide a good environment for running the script against the project

Comment: How does that compare to using NuGet?  I would assume that the NuGet console is hooked into the DTE somehow.

Comment: Well NuGet uses powershell when it installs....I'm actually researching powershell for that reason.

Comment: Jared, that's useful. I already have PowerGUI and I'm a little confused about how to use it. My biggest issue is that the scripts I've tried to run say that they're compiled with a newer version than what I have, but I just dl'd it. Still working on this one.

Answer (score 4):

You should also look at [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com), which provides a deep integration of the DTE in a custom PowerShell host.

Comment: Wow, StudioShell is pretty awesome!