# Using Powershell scripts to automate Formatting Config File

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, configuration, nuget, code-formatting

I'm really weak in Powershell scripting and hoping someone can put the following pieces together to help me solve the following problem.

**Background:**
Whenever I update my NuGet packages, they often will touch the app.config and web.config files in my project, thereby, changing the formatting. 
This has been reported here without a solution.

[Nuget and web.config formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828208/nuget-and-web-config-formatting)

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1511

**Goal:**
Ultimately, what I'd like to do is have a context menu in Visual Studio (e.g. at the solution level)
that gets a list of all app.config and web.config
and apply the CTRL+K+D to format the config files
(where we have it set to have one attribute per line)

Basically, I'm looking for a modified script that I can hook up to Visual Studio context menu (at solution level) that will read only the relevant config files. OR, alternatively, executed on file save (for relevant config files).
THANKS!

**My starting point is from** 
a) Mark Melville showing how to execute a powershell script from within the context menu in Visual Studio

[How do I run a PowerShell script from Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035994/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-from-visual-studio-2010)

b) and Scripts from Phil Haack and David Fowl

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/22/an-obsessive-compulsive-guide-to-source-code-formatting.aspx/

https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/984358

**For reference, cut and pasted from above links,
Adding context menu to Visual Studio**

Add an "External Tool". Go to Tools > External Tools. Add a new one with these settings:

- Title: Run with Powershell
- Command: powershell.exe
- Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "$(ItemPath)"
- Initial Directory: $(ItemDir)
- Check "Use Output Window"
- If you plan to use scripts that require arguments, check "Prompt For Arguments"

Take note of the position your tool is in the list (1,2, etc...) Click OK.

- Now go to Tools > Customize,  Commands tab,  select Context Menu, and
  choose "Project and Solution Context Menus | Item".
- Click "Add Command..".
- Choose Tools category, and choose "External Command X"
  where x is the position your tool was in the list.
- Click OK.
- Move it to the position you want in the menu, and click "Modify Selection"
  to give it a friendly name,
- add keyboard shortcuts, etc..
- Click Close.

Right click your .ps1 file in the solution explorere and enjoy. (NOTE: I also did this for cmd.exe to run .bat files.)

**For reference, cut and pasted from above links,
powershell script to format document**

```
# Print all project items
Recurse-Project -Action {param($item) "`"$($item.ProjectItem.Name)`" is a $($item.Type)" }

# Function to format all documents based on https://gist.github.com/984353
function Format-Document {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string[]]$ProjectName
    )
    Process {
        $ProjectName | %{ 
                        Recurse-Project -ProjectName $_ -Action { param($item)
                        if($item.Type -eq 'Folder' -or !$item.Language) {
                            return
                        }

                        $window = $item.ProjectItem.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}')
                        if ($window) {
                            Write-Host "Processing `"$($item.ProjectItem.Name)`""
                            [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(100)
                            $window.Activate()
                            $Item.ProjectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument')
                            $Item.ProjectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.RemoveAndSort')
                            $window.Close(1)
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}

function Recurse-Project {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string[]]$ProjectName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$Action
    )
    Process {
        # Convert project item guid into friendly name
        function Get-Type($kind) {
            switch($kind) {
                '{6BB5F8EE-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}' { 'File' }
                '{6BB5F8EF-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}' { 'Folder' }
                default { $kind }
            }
        }

        # Convert language guid to friendly name
        function Get-Language($item) {
            if(!$item.FileCodeModel) {
                return $null
            }

            $kind = $item.FileCodeModel.Language
            switch($kind) {
                '{B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'C#' }
                '{B5E9BD33-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'VB' }
                default { $kind }
            }
        }

        # Walk over all project items running the action on each
        function Recurse-ProjectItems($projectItems, $action) {
            $projectItems | %{
                $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    ProjectItem = $_
                    Type = Get-Type $_.Kind
                    Language = Get-Language $_
                }

                & $action $obj

                if($_.ProjectItems) {
                    Recurse-ProjectItems $_.ProjectItems $action
                }
            }
        }

        if($ProjectName) {
            $p = Get-Project $ProjectName
        }
        else {
            $p = Get-Project
        }

        $p | %{ Recurse-ProjectItems $_.ProjectItems $Action } 
    }
}

# Statement completion for project names
Register-TabExpansion 'Recurse-Project' @{
    ProjectName = { Get-Project -All | Select -ExpandProperty Name }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look for a VS extension that will do it automatically for you. For ex. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496 you may have to just do some searching. There is a lot of code formatting extensions out there.

Comment: yes, there are lots of extensions out there... including Resharper and PowerTools/toys. But these often don't have the fine control, e.g. filtering on config files only, or on the entire solution. Remember, the workaround is to open the config file and CTRL+K+D. It's not that much effort, so any solution just needs to save me from having to do this for all my projects.